# Difference between `let case(value)` and `case(let value)` (Swift)

Tags: swift

Lets say we have an `enum` with associated values:

```
enum A {
    case a1(x: Int)
    case a2(y: String)
}
```

And some function that switches on this `enum`:

```
func doSomething(a: A) {
    
    switch a {
    case .a1(let x):
        print("a1 let \(x)")
    case let .a2(y):
        print("let a2 \(y)")
    }
}
```

For example:

```
var x = A.a1(x: 1)
var y = A.a2(y: "hello")
doSomething(a: x) // Prints a1 let 1
doSomething(a: y) // Prints let a2 hello
```

As you notice I can use the syntax `case .a1(let x)` and `case let .a2(y)` with no apparent difference.

So I wanted to understand: are there valid reasons to have both syntaxes, or they are purely for convenience? For example: are there a lower-level (compiler, memory) difference between those options? Are there any examples when one or the other wouldn't work as well? Thanks

Comment: The only case you really need to use let/var inside the parentheses is if one associated value is variable`var` and another is constant `let` otherwise I would just use `case let` (if all associated values are constant) or `case var` (if all associated values are variables).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As you notice I can use the syntax case .a1(let x) and case let .a2(y) with no apparent difference.

You're right, there's very little difference between these two syntaxes — the `case let` syntax is for convenience.

> are there valid reasons to have both syntaxes, or they are purely for convenience? For example: are there a lower-level (compiler, memory) difference between those options?

Yes, but it best applies to `enum` cases with more than one associated value, as it allows you to avoid having to repeat `let` for every single associated value in the case:

```swift
enum A {
    case a1(x: Int)
    case a2(y: String)
    case a3(x: Int, y: String)
    case a4(x: Int, y: String, z: Double)
}

let a: A = ...
switch a {
// Inner `let`:
case .a1(let x):
    print(x)

// Equivalent outer `let`:
case let .a2(y):
    print(y)

// Inner `let`s can get repetitive:
case .a3(let x, let y):
    print(x, y)

// More convenient outer `let`s:
case let .a4(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)
}
```

An explanation from the [Swift language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148):

> If all of the associated values for an enumeration case are extracted as constants, or if all are extracted as variables, you can place a single var or let annotation before the case name, for brevity

This is a purely syntactic convenience, and makes absolutely no difference in compilation.

---

If you're curious about how this shakes out from the language grammar:

- [`switch` statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_switch-statement) have a list of switch cases
- Regular cases (non-`default` cases) have a [case label](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_case-label) (which has one or more case items)
- [Case items](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_case-item-list) are bound as patterns
- [Patterns](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_pattern) are where the syntax branches:

  1. In the `case let .a4(...)` variant, the `pattern` is bound as a [value binding pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_value-binding-pattern) whose internal pattern binds as an [enum case pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_enum-case-pattern)
  2. In the `case .a3(let...)` variant, the `pattern` is bound directly as an enum case pattern, whose [tuple pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_tuple-pattern) contents each bind a value binding pattern

The grammar technically allows for a lot of flexibility here, but the compiler ensures that you either have a `var`/`let` outside of the case label itself, or bind each variable inside of the case with a `var`/`let` internally

Answer (score 2):

This is only a syntactic difference. Consequently, `x` is bound to the enum case's associated value whether you write `let .someCase(x)` or `.someCase(let x)` as the [pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html) of the switch case.

#### `.someCase(let x)`

This is an [enum case pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID424), with a [value-binding pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID422) (`let x`) within it. Within the value-binding pattern, there is an [identifier pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID421) `x`. As an abstract syntax tree, it looks like this:

```
  enum case pattern
         |
value-binding pattern
         |
  identifier pattern
```

#### `let .someCase(x)`

In this case, the value-binding pattern is the root of the tree instead:

```
value-binding pattern
         |
  enum case pattern
         |
  identifier pattern
```

Note that the syntax for value-binding patterns is very flexible, any kind of pattern can follow the keyword `let`/`var`.

```
value-binding-pattern ::= 'let' pattern | 'var' pattern
```

According to the [value-binding patterns](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID422) section of the Swift guide,

> Identifiers patterns within a value-binding pattern bind new named variables or constants to their matching values.

In both cases, the identifier pattern is nested within the value-binding pattern, directly or indirectly. Therefore, `x` is bound to the matched associated value in the same way.

It might seem like writing `let` first thing in the pattern is always a good idea since it binds all the identifiers to the newly matched values in one go. But sometimes you don't actually want to bind everything:

```
enum Foo {
    case someCase(Int, Int, Int)
}

func someFunction(someParameter: Int, foo: Foo) {
    switch foo {
    // if you wrote "let .someCase(someParameter, y, z)" here,
    // then someParameter would be bound to the associated value, rather than
    // the function's parameter!
    case .someCase(someParameter, let y, let z):
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, as both are very informative. But went with an earlier one. Thanks for the answer nevertheless!